# Log php filesystem activity

Tags: php, apache, security, logging

Short: is it possible to log when php writes to the filesystem? This may not necessarily be through php; it could be modsec or lfd or some other lower-level package.

Detail: malware creators are getting very inventive with their operations. Backdoors, sometimes, are difficult to find. Problem solved, if there's a means to log when php writes files (namely, its mal-files, but logs log everything ofc), along with the script/loc that called the write.

Comment: just remove write permissions for the user which apache runs as.. Also this is more security.stackexchange.com no ?

Comment: See `strace`. Also: problem *not* solved, if the malware hooks the system calls and pretends nothing is happening (but that's a rootkit problem then).